Is there any contemporary philosopher who defends the circularity of time?
I personally think that time is circular, but most defenders of this view are mystical thinkers or continental philosophers. I am curious about the topic and would like to know if there are any philosophers in the analytic tradition who hold the view, or at least discuss it or present arguments in its favor.

I can't even think of any non-contemporary philosopher who defends the circularity of time as such. The idea of eternal return used to be popular, but that has events recurring in linear time. Huemer argued for a modern version of it recently. Circular time would require closed timelike curves, which only came up in the 20th century and are entertained in time travel scenarios, but not really defended.

I don't think there are in the Analytic tradition. But thinkers like Richard Rorty have been eroding the division.

"Rulers, statesmen and peoples are primarily referred to the lessons
of historical experience. But what experience and history teach is
that nations and governments have never learned anything from history
and have never acted in accordance with the lessons that could have
been drawn from it."
-Hegel, in his essay Lectures on the Philosophy of History


"Hegel remarks somewhere that all great world-historic facts and
personages appear, so to speak, twice. He forgot to add: the first
time as tragedy, the second time as farce".
-Marx, in his essay The Eighteenth Brumaire of Louis Bonaparte

Hegel and Marx certainly continue to have influence on modern thinkers, like say Zizek who discusses history repeating in this essay: First As Farce, Then As Tragedy? You might like this answer on the nature of dialectic reasoning, about why they saw such patterns: Relation of dialectics, as of Hegel and Marx, toward Enlightenment liberalism
We discussed social and political cycles in this thread: Pendulum Theory / Cyclical Theory in Philosophy?
Between the Fall of Rome and the Renaissance, it was much more common to see history as cyclical.
Hindu, Buddhist and Daoist cosmologies are cyclical, as was that of the Ancient Egyptians.
Roger Penrose has proposed Conformal Cyclic Cosmology, that after a very long time all particles with mass will decay into massless ones, and that will cause the universe to restart.
